# Can I use Jface to build an editor to plug in in my application?

Tags: jface

I want to create an editor just like an Eclipse editor and want to plug that editor in my JSP page.

Is it possible to do so using JFace?

I looked at the following example but not sure if this will help me to get what I want.

http://www.realsolve.co.uk/site/tech/jface-text.php

Please help

Answer (score 1):

No, if you want to use JFace (and SWT, which JFace is based on) in a web page, you have to use [RAP](http://eclipse.org/rap/) instead of JSP.

Comment: So what technology can be used to provide a rich editor like eclipse editor that will fit for JSP?   I tried codemirror but it cannot do what eclipse editor can. For example, eclipse editor shows the list of java methods for a specific Java object. ( for example- String s=null; s.toString() etc.)